# Any perfomance issues due to display none?

Tags: css

The website I created has so much to hide in the mobile view. Will there be any problem on its performance by using too much `display: none` on a single page?

Comment: instead of using `display:none` to hiding some content for mobile device, I would prefer to increase the page loading better use some `jquery`
you can choose  `$( " " ).remove();`

Comment: That does not increase page loading because the client has to render some javascript. Here is display:none faster then the jquery.remove, because javascript needs cpu power from the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a performance problem... not in rendering the page but in loading it over the internet.
display: none does also load all the content for your mobile site which isn't neccessary? Try to remove it from the DOM and you got also performance for loading the site

Comment: agree with TOBI, better remove it from DOM. so performance could increase in smaller devices.

Comment: you may use some jquery functions like `.remove();`

Comment: No, jQuery is javascript and javascript can only change DOM when its already loaded on the client... that does not bring any performance boost. If you want some performance speedup at loading the page, you have do decide on the server, which page you have to deliver. So there are only these elements will  be delivered to the device which are really neccessary. You should decide, what you want... responsive website oder a mobile first site

Answer (score 2):

**No** there is no performance difference due to the usage of the `display:none`. When you use `display: none` then you tell the Html engine to completely ignore the element and all his children. The elements are not in the [render tree](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#Render_tree_construction)

Answer (score 0):

No There won't be any. But if you are really hiding stuff and a lots of it. Try to remove it from DOM all together instead of hiding it. Atleast that stuff which could have bindings or watches on it.

Answer (score 0):

> Please note that a display of 'none' does not create an invisible box;
>   it creates no box at all. CSS includes mechanisms that enable an
>   element to generate boxes in the formatting structure that affect
>   formatting but are not visible themselves. Please consult the section
>   on visibility for details.

[Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html)

Doesn't create a box => more performance.